# Colloquialism for “see you later”

Tags: expressions, oral, salutations

I have heard/seen both "À tout à l'heure" and "À tout alors" used for the English phrase "see you later". Are these both correct?

Comment: I don't think it's been mentioned clearly, but *À toute* is short for *À tout à l'heure*. And there's no reason not to find *alors* after it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure it was “*À tout alors*”? I think you've heard “*À toute, alors !*”. Here is an exemple of context:

> — Je vais à la conférence du logiciel libre cet après-midi.
>
> — Ah oui ? J'y vais aussi !
>
> — Cool ! À toute, alors ! / Cool ! Alors à toute !

A translation might be:

> — I'm going to the free software conference this afternoon.
>
> — Oh really? I'll be there too.
>
> — Nice! See you later, then!

And the first one, *À tout à l'heure* is right. This is the full form of the expression. Even if you can say *À toute, alors*, it is more colloquial indeed.

Comment: Quick question; what's the J'y short for?

Comment: Here, `y` is the pronoun. It refers to the place you are going to. See https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y (Y²). « I. − [Y, pron. adv., représente le lieu où l'on est ou le lieu où l'on va. Il s'oppose ainsi à en qui représente le lieu d'origine] » Here are some examples : https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/fle/les-pronoms-en-et-y-62.php

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct, the first one *à tout à l'heure* (without a **s** at the end) is the most common.

And the second one *à toute, alors*, is more familiar. It is a contraction of the first example (https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_toute), with *alors* added at the end, it can be translated to :

> See you later, then.

But they mean the same thing in the end.

Answer (score 4):

You misheard - *à tout alors* doesn't exist, that's your interpretation of *à tout à l'heure*.  The most common really colloquial expression is *à plus*, short for *à plus tard*.

Either one can be followed by *alors*, as any other sentence would in conversation - just like Americans would start anything with *so*

Comment: And it's worth mentioning that 'à plus' is sometimes abbreviated 'A+', especially in emails.

Comment: Good point JonathanZ, that's the most common written form